# Is it safe to put the file containing the database password in var/www?

Tags: apache

I don't want to save the file containing the database password in the webroot of apache so I moved it to var/www (the server root) and include it from there.

Is this creating new security issues which weren't there before or can I leave it there?

Comment: I always read "don't store database credentials in a file, it's unsafe" but never hear practical alternatives and, in the end, everybody does it. But you don't want to publish the file for the entire internet to download it. Not sure how `etc/www` became the server root in your machine (do you mean `/var/www`?) but it's possibly the worst place. You need to store sensitive information *outside* the document root.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Oh, you're right, of course it's `var/www`, I just corrected it. In my version of apache, the webroot is `var/www/html`, I think only in older versions the `var/www` is the public webroot.

Comment: Right, if `/var/www/html` is the public tree, `/var/www` should be fine. But now I think about it, `/etc/www` looks like a sensible place to put settings :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález :D Yes, this really looks life a safe place. But anyways, I will deactivate public access to my database whenever I don't need admin access to it, so all the security questions here revolve around the time I need to directly connect to my database.

Answer (score 0):

The security issue that it creates, is that anyone who has access to the server, can get your DB credentials. Also, depending on the file and folder, there is a possibility that the file can be downloaded (really depends on the file and security settings on your web app). The industry standard solution is to encrypt the credentials in that file.

Comment: So you encrypt the credentials, fine. Where do you safely store the encryption key?

Comment: In our company, we use some password vault and only a few people have access to the vault.

Comment: Also, our website is in .Net, which has a built-in solution for encryption of the credentials in config files. The credentials must be encrypted on the server and I think the machine key is pat of the key used for encryption.

Comment: How does ther DB access the password?

Comment: @zaph: You mean DBA?

Comment: The database needs the password, how does it access the password if they are in a password vault?

Comment: @zaph: Let's say you have a database called ABC. Your DBA, assigns a username and a password (let's say User1/Password1). That part is done the usual way. Now these credentials are stored in a configuration file on the server, to be used by a web application. Instead of saving the credentials as plain text in the config file, we encrypt them. The application reads the credentials from the config file, decrypts them and then connects to the database.  In .net, there is a builtin library that handles the decrypting task automatically, meaning the developers are not hard coding the encryption key

Comment: The problem just moved to the key that is used to decrypt the credentials from the config file. How is that encryption key saved, in the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137879/discussion-between-sparrow-and-zaph).